# How can I select half of the points in my curve with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

A quick question, I've been trying to use the geometry nodes to make a simple chain, all I need is a way to reference the points in the curve in a manner I can select half of them to rotate them by 90º in the Y direction; I need some information from the Instances or Points that I can check with a Math node to set up the Selection Booleans, something like an ID number which I can divide and check if its an even or odd number.[image]

Any ideas of which field can have this informartion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this is what you want,try such nodes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, it seems to work, thanks a lot!